# Content search and content type

Tags: search, content-type, publishing-site, content-search-web-part, kql

In SP 2013 on-prem publishing site, I have a **Content Search WebPart** that shows a list of pages by querying for the custom content type id, and it worked fine until I edited the navigation settings on the site to use managed navigation based on a Term set. Now the content search web part is no longer showing the pages that are created before I edited the navigation settings. It only shows pages that are created at a later time, even though the "old" pages are there in the pages library.

I inspected the pages with SharePoint manager, and the old pages and new pages have same content type id. I checked in Crawl log and found the old pages to have been successfully crawled there. The "old" pages are in the search index, use the exact same page layout and content type, but they can not be shown in **Content Search WebPart**.

Anybody else here that has had the same issue?
Any tips for me?

Comment: If you edit the Content Search Web Part and switch to Advanced Mode, what's your query saying on the TEST tab in the Query Test box?

Comment: Hi Mark, I get the same result. Basically, I have found that the items that are not visible can not be found on search also - that's why they are not showing in the content search. Why they have suddenly become enemy with the search engine, I don't know (except from me editing a setting in navigation). I have re indexed the library, done index reset and run full crawl several times. To no avail. I don't understand this.. SharePoint works in mysterious ways...

Comment: Could it be that your Result Set definition is too limiting? Maybe you could paste the query from the result set in here so we can have a look?

Comment: Hi, no, it is not limiting, I have only 2 elements in the pages library. My Query is like this ContentTypeId:0x32432948392048GUID*  ... I am using December 2014 CU, maybe I need to do an update..

Comment: Try editing the page and do a check-out and check-in again. Let the search crawl run again

Comment: If you have only 2 pages, try re-publishing them & do a full crawl. If it fails, then delete those page and re-create them & wait for the search index to finish & then give it a try. Also, why not bypass the search & use List View webpart?

Comment: Are you sure the older pages are considered published and approved?  We had a similar problem several years ago, not at all related to navigation changes, but we had an old page library with thousands of pages, and the client decided they wanted to turn on content approval.  None of the old pages were considered approved, so they all disappeared from search, but the newer pages were approved within a few minutes of being created, and were thus showing up in search.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the issue could be related to the changes you made to the site navigation. When you changed to managed navigation, it's possible that the URLs of your pages changed. This can cause the Content Search Web Part to have trouble finding those pages because it's looking for the old URLs.

To confirm this, you can try doing a search for one of the "old" pages using the search box on the site. If the page shows up in the search results, then it's likely an issue with the Content Search Web Part configuration.

---

To fix the issue, you can try editing the query for the Content Search Web Part to include the updated URLs that were created with managed navigation. You may also need to update any other places in your site where those old URLs are referenced, such as in links or navigation menus.